# Sharing an arena between players in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-memory

The problem that lead me here is conceptual. I want to create an arena for a game. This arena will be a sort of web service because I've got to expose it for two purposes :

- On the demonstration website where someone can play against a computer. On the demonstration website where the one that created an artificial intelligency can see animations of their parties.
- On an API which the artificial intelligencies request to play together.

As a matter of fact I have to organize a programming contest for those AI. My problem is that I'm a little blocked as I've got a big panel of technologies, some I master, some I just heard a little, some I just don't understand.

My matter is that when 2, 3 or 4 AI play together I don't know how to deal with the turns.

My very first idea was about socket.

IA open a socket with a peculiar URL of my website and data are exchanged within the socket (It's your turn, here is my hit, Oh dear it's a bad hit try again...). I don't know if it is the right thing to do and if I can share the arena between all IA like that.

I thought about a simple http exchange as we can do with old javascript API, but it brings some difficulties as the request close each time.

I use ASP.NET to do this web service/ website in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need real time (it's turn by turn).

You can also have a key/id for each arena, and clients can poll a webservice on a regular basis to get status of the game (*It's your turn, here is my hit, Oh dear it's a bad hit try again...*)

For the web part, you can use JSON and Ajax to communicate with the server efficiently. But it's always the client that asks the server.

--

I don't know what it will be with sockets (with HTML5), or sockets with desktop clients when you have a lot of simultaneous user.

Comment: Ok Say me if I understand well : you want me to store the arenas in database (SQL or NoSQL no matters)

Comment: Yes, as well as current status, and may be the detail of each turn (to make replays, statistics, in case of failure during a game...)

Comment: Ok. It was something I thought good but I had a doubt about the efficiency.

Comment: You can still have all the arenas "in-memory" server side! Database (or XML file) can be helpfull if you have to many arenas in game at the same time, and not enough memory to handle them.

Comment: Ok, so I think I will take this solution. I accept your answer and if I got question I come back here.